# Run Softether and Apache on the same server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, apache2, softether

The question is pretty much in the title. I'm currently running Apache with a https cert, and softether on two different servers currently. But due to cost cutting measures, I will be installing both programs on one server. 
Is there any way that I can run Softether and Apache on the same server, with both programs using port 443? The server is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks
Nikrox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't put them both on the same port on the same public IP address. However you can get a second public IP and bind each service respectively. This is likely to be cheap [on aws](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for example)

Configuration for apache is something like

```
# change in /etc/apache2/ports.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 192.170.2.1:443
</IfModule>
```

and the equivalent configuration for softether;
https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN/pull/202
(looks like that option was very recently added...

If there is no scope for additional IP addresses, an alternative would be to move the VPN service to a different port, say 8443;
https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/3._SoftEther_VPN_Server_Manual/3.3_VPN_Server_Administration#3.3.6_Listener_Ports

Comment: It worked  for me but I ended up just crippling both as the VPS wasn't powerful enough. Just note that the Softether Listen IP setting is only available in the github repo for now.